# React Material-ui form component

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, material-ui

I have a problem I can't get the data values ​​from the formContent component. Can you help me please. You will find the codesandbox link

[summaryForm](https://codesandbox.io/s/formulaire-v2-forked-www0t1?file=/src/components/summaryForm.jsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `App` (root component) with the `AppContext` provider.

1. Move `AppContext` from `formContent` to `App` component and create context with values and setters and other functions you want.

```
export const AppContext = createContext({
  activeStep: 0,
  values: [],
  handleFormChange() {},
  handleNext() {},
  handleBack() {}
});

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    nni: "",
    nom: "",
    prenom: "",
    email: "",
    typeHabilitation: "",
    perimetreHabilitation: ""
  });

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ values, setValues }}>
      <Form />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

2. Now use this context in both `formulaireValidation` and `SummaryForm` components.

```
export default function formulaireValidation({ submitForm }) {
   ...
   ...
  const { values, setValues } = useContext(AppContext);
  ...
  ...

}

export default function SummaryForm(props) {
  const { values, handleBack, handleNext } = useContext(AppContext);
  ...
  ...
}
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit formulaire v2 (forked)]

Comment: @Mame-dev, check this out !!